# Numpy: Fast approach to extract rows from an array using an 2D index array

Tags: numpy

I have 2 arrays a and b:

```
N,D,V,W = 2,3,4,5
a = np.random.randint(0,V,N*D).reshape(N,D)
a
array([[2, 3, 3],
       [2, 0, 3]])

b = np.random.randint(0,10,V*W).reshape(V,W)
b
array([[0, 1, 0, 5, 5],
       [0, 3, 6, 8, 7],
       [8, 8, 9, 0, 9],
       [4, 6, 3, 3, 1]])
```

What I need to do is to replace every element of array a with a row from array b using the array a element value as the row index of array b.

At the moment I'm doing it this way which works fine:

```
b[a.ravel(),:].reshape(*a.shape,-1)
array([[[8, 8, 9, 0, 9],
        [4, 6, 3, 3, 1],
        [4, 6, 3, 3, 1]],

       [[8, 8, 9, 0, 9],
        [0, 1, 0, 5, 5],
        [4, 6, 3, 3, 1]]])
```

However it seems this approach is a bit slow.

I tested it with:

```
N,D,V,W = 20000,64,100,256
```

and it took an average of 674ms on my laptop(8 core, 16 ram)

Can someone please recommend an faster yet still simple approach?

Comment: You're trying to create over an entire gigabyte of array. Probably 1.3 gigs on Windows or 2.6 gigs on Linux. It's going to take a while.

Comment: That's a normal 'numpy' operation.